# Typescript subclass factory

Tags: javascript, typescript, mixins

I recently read an article on [javascript mixins as subclass factories](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/), which proposed the following pattern for creating mixins:

```
let MyMixin = (superclass) => class extends superclass {  
  foo() {
    console.log('foo from MyMixin');
  }
};
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
class MyClass extends MyMixin(MyBaseClass) {  
  /* ... */
}
```

I wanted to see if this worked in TypeScript, but I get the following error:

> error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

Although it will still compile into working javascript, nothing I do will get rid of this error.

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Is parameterising a superclass like this impossible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work with generics (at least, I couldn't make it to work):

```
type SuperclassConstructor<T> = { new (): T };

let MyMixin = <T>(superclass: SuperclassConstructor<T>) => {
    return class extends superclass {  
        foo() {
            console.log('foo from MyMixin');
        }
    };
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20SuperclassConstructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20MyMixin%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(superclass%3A%20SuperclassConstructor%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20superclass%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('foo%20from%20MyMixin')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyBaseClass%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass%20extends%20MyMixin(MyBaseClass)%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%0A%7D))

Saying:

> Base constructor return type 'T' is not a class or interface type

As it needs a concrete class there, you can just have a base class for all classes that you want to use with this mixin:

```
class Base { }
type SuperclassConstructor = { new (): Base };

let MyMixin = (superclass: SuperclassConstructor) => {
    return class extends superclass {  
        foo() {
            console.log('foo from MyMixin');
        }
    };
}

class MyBaseClass extends Base {}

class MyClass extends MyMixin(MyBaseClass) {  
  /* ... */
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Base%20%7B%20%7D%0Atype%20SuperclassConstructor%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20Base%20%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20MyMixin%20%3D%20(superclass%3A%20SuperclassConstructor)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20class%20extends%20superclass%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('foo%20from%20MyMixin')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyBaseClass%20extends%20Base%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MyClass%20extends%20MyMixin(MyBaseClass)%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%0A%7D))